# Custom highcharts legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using HighCharts v2.3.1 to visualize some data, and I have a question about the legend:

Is it possible to have a legend that is not specifically tied to a data series in the chart? I have a couple of charts that is used to visualize mobile network data. In these charts I separate the data on systems (GSM, UMTS, LTE, etc.), and for most of them the default chart legend is exactly what I need. In those cases, each system has a separate data series in the chart, so when you toggle a system, you toggle the visibility of a data series.

For one of the charts however, I want to have the same kind of selector control, but this time the system selection is instead used in the server-side data access algorithm to calculate the data to be visualized. Is it possible to use a similar control as the legend for this, or do I have to create a separate one for this purpose? I thought it would be nice to have the system selection control looking the same for all charts even though it is used differently "behind the scenes".

So to sum up: In one case The system selection control is tied directly to data series, and all series are loaded to the client. This is supported out of the box in highcharts. In the other case each system is not directly mapped to one data series, and when you toggle a system on/off I want to go to the server and generate new data for the whole chart.

Does it seem doable to create a control like this, that basically looks and acts the same way as a legend, but is used differently?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible using [legendItemClick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick) event handler, so there in callback you can call AJAX to get new data.

Comment: Yes, that seem like the correct way to hook it up to my business logic, so thanks alot! But I also need to find a way to explicitly set the list of legend items (since they are not mapped one-to-one with a data series). Do you know how to do that as well?

Comment: So you would like to add your own items to legend?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I need to control the legend items "manually", and not have them mapped directly to the data series.

Comment: You can set useHTML and then add items as html by jquery, and add catch event.